The knight cannot jump over its tail
Consider a chess knight that will draw a line on the board after each move between the square it came from and the square it moved to.
What is the maximum number of moves that this knight can do on a regular 8x8 board, if it visits no square twice and may not jump across a line it has already drawn (its tail)?
Here is an example of allowed and disallowed moves:

The red move is not allowed because it would cross the previous line from the green move.

EDIT: new high score

 35


 

Previous best attempt:

 33

moves, tying @Retudin's score (once they've edited in the latest suggestions).

 

The top left corner doesn't really look optimal, though.

Nice! Apparently this new high score is optimal! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_uncrossed_knight%27s_path) Since the longest paths are only known up to a board size of 9x9, I suspect that there won't be a clean argument for optimality though

What happens if you start from a square not on the optimal path?

@Simd not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "What happens"?

What length path can you get starting from them?

@Simd Why would being on or off the path be a useful predictor of that?

@Albert.Lang I think SimdOct's question is about the maximum length of an uncrossed path if there is a condition that the starting point should be a3 (or some other square not in the path given in the answer). But, it will still be 35 since we can rotate the board to start from any square as we wish.

Without any proof of optimality and just for fun, here is a solution with

 27 moves


 


Moves: (no proof of optimality)

 32 31 

Path:

 


You can replace e6-g5-f3-h4 with e6-g7-f5-h4 and then e2-g3-h1-f2-d1-e3 with c1-e2-g1-h3-f2-g4-e3.

Yeah, using g7 to free f3g4 seems obvious in hindsight, and indeed allows an extra move

My best so far is a solution with

 31 30  moves,

seen here:

 

(This is likely still not optimal.)


 Another (optimal) path of length 35


